# How can i enable google direction api for my project?

Tags: java, android

i dont have valid account for payment since i am from nepal. is that compulsory to create "Credentials" in order to use google direction api? help me

Comment: you can use vpn to change your location

Comment: @ArsalImam how changing location will help in this case?

Comment: He said, he is in nepal and have issues with billing that's why I mentioned him

Comment: You may be better off contacting Google's support at https://support.google.com/googleplay/thread/new?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

yes it is compulsory to create credentials because using this you will set where and how you can use your google api key. And connection of payment account will also be necessary for this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not able to use Google Maps in your app, try [Mapbox](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/overview/), everything is free and is also has its own directions api.